# Google Drive API の drive.file スコープが他のユーザーのファイルにアクセスする権限を持っていないのは仕様ですか？

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Google Drive APIを使用しています。`drive.file` スコープは公式ドキュメントには以下のように書かれています。

> Create new Drive files, or modify existing files, that you open with an app or that the user shares with an app while using the Google Picker API or the app's file picker.

リンクを知っている全員が編集可能な共有設定がされているフォルダ内に、ユーザーAのアクセストークンを使用してアプリケーションを実行しファイルを作成した場合、ユーザーAのアクセストークンを使用してそのファイルを取得することはできますが、他のユーザーBのアクセストークンで同じアプリケーションを実行してそのファイルを取得することはできませんでした。これは仕様でしょうか？

`/auth/drive` スコープではユーザーBのアクセストークンでもファイルを取得できましたが、このスコープは機密性が高いファイルにアクセスすることができるため非推奨となっています。